# Angular.js carousel using background-image

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm just wondering if anyone has any experience of creating a carousel in angular.js which uses 'background-image' rather than 'img src'?

I'm new to angular and am trying to create something similar to this - https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/half-slider/ but in angular and I'm struggling!

The half-slider example uses a background-image with background-size: cover & background-position: centre so when you view the carousel full screen the image is zoomed in on (and a fixed height) - when you view it on a mobile the image 'zooms out'

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for the reply! So far i've tried to format the images as they are (so as img nr-src) using various things like background-position, max-height, background-size etc. I've also found some code here https://mark.zealey.org/2015/05/11/background-slideshow-with-angularjs-and-bootstrap  but couldn't get it to work. I'm not an expert at angular by any means but I can see that Mark's code isn't really the angular carousel anymore, rather a bit of a workround

Comment: Do you have some code?

Comment: I've got it on github here - https://github.com/ed85w/Stream1Project/tree/test-carousel